# Ice-hockey penalty shot saves

Tags: statistics, ice-hockey, penalty-shot, goalkeeper

In ice-hockey when there is a penalty shot and player missed the net so goalkeeper didn't need to make a save, is it still counted as a save for the goalkeeper for his penalty shot save percentage? And what about shootout shots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless of when they are made, saves in hockey are defined by [shots on goal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_on_goal_(ice_hockey)).

A shot, on the other hand is any puck directed toward the net.  If the shot would have gone in the net without a save, it is said to be a shot on goal.  If the goaltender makes a save, it counts as a shot on goal.  Any shot on goal is counted as a shot, but not all shots are shots on goal.

For this reason, in overtime, during a penalty shot, or a shootout, if a puck does not go in the net, and is not stopped by the goaltender, this will not count as a save.

Comment: Would this be accurately summarised as "you can't stop something that wasn't happening"?

Comment: Um.  I suppose.  I don't think that's the title of the rule in the NHL Handbook.

Comment: Yes I know, but on the NHL web I can't find a single record where PS SA - PS Svs != PS GA. That means that there is no record where there was more shots against than saves and goals together. Or does it mean that PS SA stat doesn't show the exact number of penalty shots a goalie has faced but only those which made it to his net?

Comment: I am unaware of what these stats look like.  It sounds like the only statistics that they record are SOG, and whether a goal is recorded.  From there, save percentage and GAA can be found.  Maybe they don't record shots that don't test the keep.